# Using pyobjc-framework-Quartz in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, core-graphics, python-2.x, quartz

I've installed the library '[pyobjc-framework-Quartz](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc-framework-Quartz/)'

```
pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```

And in Python2, the following lines work perfectly:

```
provider = Quartz.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(input_file_path)
pdf = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider)
```

But in Python3, I get the error message:

> provider = Quartz.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(input_file_path)

> ValueError: depythonifying 'char', got 'str' of 1

I've tried converting to char*

```
from ctypes import *
path = c_char_p(input_file_path)
```

but nothing seems to work. Can someone explain the error?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out. The problem is that the string `input_file_path` in python3 is a Unicode string, and needs to be converted to a binary string before use in objc APIs.

```
input_file_path_converted = input_file_path.encode('utf-8')
provider = Quartz.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(input_file_path_converted)
```

.
(Except that it only work for filenames with standard "ASCII" range alphanumerics...)